# MongoDB InsertBatch exceptions

Tags: exception, mongodb, insert

For example I have new sequence of documents to write with _ids:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

and already stored collection of documents with _ids:
[3,4,7].

I want to store my new sequence with command InsertBatch and do not wanna to check every _id for existing. Ofcourse Mongo will throw exception because of collision and collection will have only part of new sequence:
[3,4,7,1,2]

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: What's the desired outcome? Would you have two documents with _id 3? Alternately, would you want to keep the old version, or the new version?

Comment: All _ids are unique and I want to keep old documents;) So I need to write [1,2,5,6]. Ok, I could find all collisions, remove them from new sequence and run BatchInsert on edited sequence, but maybe solution could be more pretty;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 2.0, you can set the `continueOnError` flag to `false` to achieve this behavior. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Inserting#Inserting-Bulkinserts for details, and consult the API documentation for your driver to find out how to use this from your application.